# Custom theme for module?

Tags: 7, blocks, theming

I am creating a new module in drupal 7 called coolmodule and I'm trying to figure out how to bind content to the file `sites/all/modules/coolmodule/coolmodule.tpl.php` file.  Here's the block view code in my coolmodule.module;

```
function coolmodule_block_view($delta = '') {

    $block['subject'] = t('My Special Module');


    $block['content'] = theme('coolmodule', array('myvar' => 'helloworld'));

    return $block;
}
```

But for some reason, pages with this block does not render `sites/all/modules/coolmodule/coolmodule.tpl.php`.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you are missing a [hook_theme()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7) function

see you defined a theme for your block by using:

```
$block['content'] = theme('coolmodule', array('myvar' => 'helloworld'));
```

but you never told it how to relate your theme with the template file, this work is done in `hook_theme()` function.

```
function coolmodule_theme() {
    $items['coolmodule'] = array(
        'template' => 'coolmodule',   // here comes your template name
        'render element' => 'content'
    );

    return $items;
}
```

Don't forget to clear your cache